# Clear cache on CodeIgniter using wildcard

Tags: codeigniter, caching

CodeIgniter [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/caching.html) specified only two-ways to delete cache. They are:

`$this->cache->delete('cache_item_id')`
 - for deleting individual cache thru ID

`$this->cache->clean()`
 - for deleting ALL cache

My website have static and dynamic content and I would like to delete all the cache on the latter only.

I'm looking for something like `->delete("latest*")` that will delete "latest-video", "latest-video-funny", "latest-video-music", "latest-article", etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've got it working, calling `$this->cache->cache_info();` will fetch a multidimensional array of all saved cache. The array keys inside the fetch array are the `cache_item_id` so I can just do the following.

```
$wildcard = 'latest';
$all_cache = $this->cache->cache_info();
foreach ($all_cache as $cache_id => $cache) :
   if (strpos($cache_id, $wildcard) !== false) :
      $this->cache->delete($cache_id);
   endif;
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a helper that does this, you can find it [here](https://github.com/stevenbenner/codeigniter-cache-helper).

how is cache created

```
  $path = $CI->config->item('cache_path');
  $cache_path = ($path == '') ? APPPATH.'cache/' : $path;
  .
  .
  .
  $uri =  $CI->config->item('base_url').
    $CI->config->item('index_page').
    $CI->uri->uri_string();
  $cache_path .= md5($uri);
```

**helper** itself

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

if ( ! function_exists('delete_cache'))
{
    function delete_cache($uri_string)
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $path = $CI->config->item('cache_path');
        $cache_path = ($path == '') ? APPPATH.'cache/' : $path;

        $uri =  $CI->config->item('base_url').
            $CI->config->item('index_page').
            $uri_string;

        $cache_path .= md5($uri);

        if (file_exists($cache_path))
        {
            return unlink($cache_path);
        }
        else
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
}
```

all credits go to `Steven Benner`, his [blog](http://stevenbenner.com/2010/12/caching-with-codeigniter-zen-headaches-and-performance/).

usage:

`delete_cache('/blog/comments/123');`

Comment: I have not tried this helper myself but it seems like it's only for File-based caching and rely on `$db['default']['cache_on'] = TRUE;` found on `config/database.php`. I'm using APC and I'm adding cache thru `$this->cache->save('cache_item_id', 'data_to_cache');`.